# Container registry push

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I am trying to push a docker image to the google cloud container registry.  However I keep getting unauthorized.  This is on a windows machine.

I have tried several things, first I tried setting up a publish using visual studio 2019 community.  Then I finally tried the console and actually saw the error unauthorized.

Here is what I tried:

```
docker push us.gcr.io:443/my-project-id/mycontainer
```

It acts like it's going then tells me I don't have permissions

It then suggests the advanced methods of authentication which leads me to create a json key file.  For simplicity sake I name the key file something easy like "keyfile.json".

I then follow the advanced instructions.

I start with this:

```
set /p PASS=<keyfile.json
```

when I hit enter, I get a command prompted and go ahead and type this:

```
docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://us.gcr.io
```

I get the error: `docker login requires at most 1 argument`

Finally, I have discovered I can use google's repository and build tools this puts the image in the repository, but I would like to be able to upload it manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read and followed all the steps described here: 

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#before_you_begin

Comment: Yes, that was the first steps I followed.  The "have permissions to push" gave me a rabbit hole.  I believe I have permissions, My account is project owner so it should have all permissions.

Comment: What's your OS? Did you try other authentication method (docker-credential-gcr and  gcloud auth configure-docker)?

Comment: I hadn't  heard of the docker-credential-gcr option, I got excited.  I tried that, and a webpage popped up and I logged in gave access to containers.  Then tried to push and it still didn't work. :(  I had already used gcloud auth configure-docker with no luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I had this problem. What you need to do is run:

`gcloud auth configure-docker`

Read [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker)

Basically, you need to authenticate gcloud to be able to push/pull from the gcloud directory.

Answer (score 0):

For your error `docker login requires at most 1 argument` . When rereading the error message, the "at most 1 argument" indicates that the user and password weren't being processes as options. It's hard to see, but the dash is a bit longer in the code

Try this instead:

```
docker login -u my-username -p my-password registry.myclient.com
```

While it looks similar, `-u` and `-p` are not the same as `–u` and `–p` (slightly longer dash).

Now to clarify the Project:Owner role, as strange as it my sounds it does not grant you all permissions by default however if you are missing any permissions in the project (error returned will be similar `[Missing necessary permission iam*] ... Please grant the roles/iam.* role`) you will be able to [grant](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console) them to yourself.

For the purpose of pushing an image to Container Register the Owner role has the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) by default

When you say you are doing this on a Windows machine do you mean that you [installed Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#before_you_begin) to push the image from your local machine? The issue could be that you are not [authenticating](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing) to the project correctly.

Or do you mean you accessed GCP throuh a browser on a Windows and run the commands from the Cloud Shell?